# Don't allow spaces in TextBox asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to avoid spaces in the Textbox and prevent the user to enter any spaces.
I tried

```
<ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="Filteredtextboxextender2" runat="server"
                                FilterType="Custom" InValidChars=" "
                                TargetControlID="tx_username">
                            </ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
```

but it didn't work. Is there any other solutions ?

Comment: What issue do you have?  Did the extender forbid all characters?  Did it allow everything, including spaces?

Comment: no it is javascript error

Comment: Can you please specify the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx), you must set `FilterMode="InvalidChars"`

Answer (score 3):

You need client side validation please check all the options available for you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb52a4x0(v=vs.100).aspx

also if I were you I would just use something like this:

```
$("#username").keypress(function(e) {
     if(e.which == 32) {
        e.preventDefault();
     }
})
```

which requires jQuery of course you can use pure Javascript if you like :)